# Problem with: Maximum upload file size: 2 MB in Google Kubernetes Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed this Wordpress kubernetes container: https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/wordpress?project

But I have a problem with upload the theme in Wordpress. 
The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

I can't find the file: php.ini. in the pods of kubernetes.

I tried to use plugin for edit php.ini in Wordpress  https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-settings/ but it's no write the file.

Could someone help me with a step-by-step guide to modify the container's yaml or other solution?

Comment: Do You reload/restart server after changes done ?

Answer (score 4):

As adviced [here](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/375), the recommended way is to mount a php config ini file. The most convenient way to expose it is using Kubernetes ConfigMaps. Pls create a new config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: wp-php-config
  namespace: default
data:
  uploads.ini: |-
    file_uploads = On
    upload_max_filesize = 256M
    post_max_size = 256M
    memory_limit = 64M
    max_execution_time = 600
```

And then expose the configMap as a volume in your pod by adding the following config to you're pod `spec.template.spec.containers`:

```
... (wordpress container specs)
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      name: php-config
      subPath: uploads.ini

(...)

volumes:
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: wp-php-config
    name: php-config
```

You might also need to adjust your ingress max upload limit. Assuming you're using nginx ingress, pls decorate it with an annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
```

If you want to apply the change to the ingress globally, search for the ingress configMap and add the setting there.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute 'kubectl get pods' to list the pods  and then get into a shell using 'kubectl exec -it [POD_NAME] -- /bin/bash'. You can then follow methods mentiond in this [link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/) to change the value.

Another option is to create a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-a-configmap) with your custom configuration similar to this [link](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/10#issuecomment-88389890) to increase the size of the upload file size.

Then you need to go to your GKE workloads and in “wordpress-1-wordpress” workload of type “StatefulSet” you need to modify the YAML file where you can add the [ConfigMap data to a Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume).

Another workaround is that, you can rebuild the image that you are using in a docker file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to resolve the issue:

1. I added these lines to my Dockerfile

   ## file upload

   RUN touch /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
       && echo "file_uploads = On \n\
   max_execution_time = 600 \n\
   upload_max_filesize = 200M \n\
   post_max_size = 200M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
2. in nginx-ingress dependencies.yml,i added these 'data' parameters in the configmap and it worked.

   kind: ConfigMap
       apiVersion: v1
       metadata:
         name: nginx-configuration
         namespace: ingress-nginx
         labels:
           app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
           app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
       data:
         proxy-body-size: "200m"
         client-max-body-size: "200m"
3. After that, `*kubectl apply -f ingress/dependencies.yml*` and i was able to upload more than 2mb.

Try this and see if it works for you